# why my player is not jumping when the player collides unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My player in the unity2d don't jump when the player collide with the tile map.

My code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 8.0f;
    public float jumpForce = 10f;
    Rigidbody2D rb ;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0, 0);
        transform.Translate(movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x,jumpForce);
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), "fps " + Mathf.Round(1.0f / Time.smoothDeltaTime).ToString());
        // Update "coin" label with actual game information
    }
}
```

Please help me before I go insane (the joke is intentional).

I tried every option in the unity editor but nothing worked

Comment: the only jump code is for when you press A, and has nothing to do with tilemaps.. so perhaps thats why

Comment: do not use `Input` inside of `FixedUpdate`.  Move the input stuff to `Update` and handle the jump in `FixedUpdate`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: try swapping the FixedUpdate with either (Update or LateUpdate).

Solution 2: divide the code into 2 segments, first cache the input vectors and then apply it in the fixed update.

Explanation: FixedUpdate is called every fixed time stamp by default this equals 0,02 seconds which means it will be called 50 times each frame, and the unity input system is updated every frame so you overriding the values.

```
private Vector2 movementForce;

private void Update(){
    movementForce = Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Vector2.right;
       
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        movementForce += Time.deltaTime * jumpForce * Vector2.Up;
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate(){
    rb.velocity = movementForce;
}
```

Comment: i will try it out

Comment: now the player is fall slower